# http get python query key - value

Tags: python, http

Write a function named "query_string" that doesn't take any parameters. The function will make an HTTPS GET request to the url "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a" with a query string containing the key-value pairs x=5, y=4, and z=5. The response from the server will be a JSON string representing an object in the format "{"answer": }" where  is a floating point Number. Return the value at the key "answer" as a float

```
    import urllib.request
    import json

    def query_string():
        response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a")
        content_string = response.read().decode()
        content=json.loads(content_string)
        return float(content['answer'])
```

output:  function query_string incorrect on input []

returned: -1.0
expected: 119.99

any idea how i can fix this issue?

Comment: You forgot about the "query string containing the key-value pairs x=5, y=4, and z=5" part.

Comment: I'm new to python, well coding in general, do i put that on the end after the /a" in the url?

Comment: Yes your url should be like "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a?x=5&y=4&z=5"

Comment: I tried that , the url you provided response = urllib.request.urlopen("fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a?x=5&y=4&z=5")  the output said : error on input []: unknown url type: 'fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a?x=5&y=4&z=5'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this using the requests package. It's super helpful. You can add the query parameters in a dict that gets passed to the `params` keyword argument

```
def query_string():
    import requests
    url=r'https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a'
    payload={
    'x':5,
    'y':4,
    'z':5}
    r=requests.get(url,params=payload)
    j=r.json()
    print(j)
```

EDIT for urllib

```
def query_string():
    url=r'https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a'
    payload={
    'x':5,
    'y':4,
    'z':5}
    url=url+'?'+urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    r=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()
    r=json.loads(r)
    return float(r['answer'])
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted to use requests as the library, but my professor has blocked that, he wants us explicitly to use urllib

Comment: @codernoob3232 Well thats super lame, but i made an edit for using only urllib

Comment: i figured it out on my own but i tested yours as well and it worked, ill upvote it as the answer as well, appreciate your help man.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import json

def query_string():
    url = "https://fury.cse.buffalo.edu/ps-api/a"
    url = url + "?x=5&y=4&z=5"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    content_string = response.read().decode()
    content=json.loads(content_string)
    return float(content['answer'])
```

ended up fixing it after a little research